# Why does the ground regenerate near my spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are blocks respawning in my Minecraft 1.3 SMP server?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18895/why-are-blocks-respawning-in-my-minecraft-1-3-smp-server)

I'm experimenting with a new server on my own machine and came across an odd problem. Regardless of where I spawn, there is a square area on the map within which, no matter what block I break, it regenerates instantaneously. It produces no material, it just comes right back.

Outside of that area, everything works just fine. If I had to guess, I'd say the area is approximately 50x50 blocks square with the center of the square at my initial spawn point.

Additionally, I'm connecting to a server running on my own machine.

Is this a known problem? I searched the official bug database but found no bug related to this. And if so, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Which mod have you installed ?

Comment: No mods installed, just downloaded the server exe about an hour ago

Comment: There should be a ops.txt where the server's installed, try to add your minecraft username and restart the server and see what it does.

Comment: Feel free to flag it as a duplicate. I searched through a few pages using different search terms though and didn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. The linked question has to deal with a bug specific to 1.3.

Comment: I'm **positive** this exact question was asked before, but I can't find it...

Comment: [Found it](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18895/is-minecraft-1-3-smp-broken)

Comment: @Raven Dreamer — The questions should probably be merged.  The original question's asker thought it was a bug, but it isn't; and the feature was added in 1.3, but isn't specific to it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This isn't a problem per se -- it's a feature! It's built in protection in Minecraft's multiplayer to hinder attempts at griefing.

So no need to panic! Your minecraft is running perfectly fine! You may just want to play out and buildings or structures some distance away from your spawn so as not to run into any troubles when you're trying to build stuff.

Comment: And now that you mention that, it makes perfect sense why that would be implemented.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Raven Dreamer's answer: If you are a server operator, you can edit the area around spawn normally.